# Building a binary file (exe) from batch script

Tags: command-line, batch

I tried to copy the contents of the exe file to another file. I want it to build an executable file. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1uGO.png) Steps I've made: 1) copy contents from "zip.exe" from notepad++ to "copyOFzip.txt" 2) renamed to copyOFZIP.exe

Why output files have different sizes? 132KB vs 186KB?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
```

Comment: Batch file can not be converted to exe file. You have to use a native programming language. batch is a scripting language.

Comment: I want to paste the exe code into the batch file

Comment: Why copy the contents of the binary file anyway? Just copy the entire file to copy the executable code and rename it (the file). If you want to change the logic of the binary/executable file then you will have to somehow decompile it, copy the decompiled code wherever needed,  and then recompile into an executable file again. Many third party apps that make batch script into an executable file though so that is possible . What are you really trying to accomplish here?

Comment: If you want to call the exe via batch then use batch script logic such as `start "" "C:\folder\app.exe"` or `call "C:\folder\app.exe"` that way.